# Application crashes on UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, exc-bad-access

so I'm implementing a custom interactive transition with Swift, and everything works well. I'm using Pan Gesture to do the interactive transition, but when I perform a fast gesture action, the application crashes at transitionContext.completeTransition(false).
Here is part of my code: 
[image]

When I start the code I set my transitionContext. When the gestures is canceled I call a custom function to animate back my transition and here is where I get:

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS

[image]

The debug navigator shows me this:

[image]

I can't find a solution for this problem, I'd like to know if someone have an idea about this particular problem or if there is something wrong I'm doing with my transition. I've already tried using Zoombies Objects, but it did not give me any idea of what's going on.

Glad with you could help me!

Comment: So my solution was set my transitionContext var as weak!